# Python. Enthought Traits. How to get a multi-column from a spreadsheet to display on the TabularEditor?

Tags: python, pywin32, enthought, win32com, traitsui

I am trying to understand how `enthought.traits` and `enthought.traitsui` work, and so far I have found it very easy to work with. I have also looked at the example https://svn.enthought.com/enthought/browser/Traits/trunk/enthought/traits/ui/demo/Advanced/Tabular_editor_demo.py?rev=17881

That shows how to put data on to a `TabularEditor`. But we have to mention the column names in the `Adapter` class. But if I have to put all my data with loads of columns and rows from a spreadsheet to the table, how would I go about it? Is there a demo file that I have missed?